# How do I install Alfresco (Enterprise Content Management software)

Tags: 10.10, installation

Give me some steps to install the Alfresco on Ubuntu 10.10.

I am new to Ubuntu so please give me some guide to install the Alfesco on Ubuntu system

Answer (score 1):

A quick installation guide is available in the official Alfresco [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/simpleinstall-enterprise-lin.html). It's targeting the Enterprise edition, but if you are to install Community the only thing that changes is the [binary file](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Download_and_Install_Alfresco).

Answer (score 0):

After unzipping the archive, the easiest way is to simply run the installer:

```
./alfresco.bin
```

This will guide you through the installation process, and is very easy to follow!

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the release you want.

open a terminal and Go into the Downloads folder..

```
cd Downloads
```

make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x filename.bin
```

then run the installer

```
sudo ./filename.bin
```

follow the instructions on the installer